# php on snow leopard server fails

Tags: apache-2.2, php, osx-snow-leopard

I tried to start php on my snow leopard server.

The file is

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

I turned on php and put the file in /Library/WebServer

I get  the following two errors in the log:

```
(8)Exec format error: exec of '/Library/WebServer/test/index.php' failed
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a `;` after phpinfo(), and to actually echo (display) the information:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```